# asp.net sending mail from google apps account not working

Tags: asp.net, smtp, gmail, send

im trying to send an email using my google apps account,
and i keep getting this error:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

when i try the same code with a normal gmail account this works.

```
        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Subject = "subject here";
        msg.Body = "body here";
        msg.To.Add("email adress here");

        var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Comment: Probably if you show the code used to send the mail we could help better.

Comment: @HasanAboShally, no worries!  The answer by Eric J. will get your email working.

Comment: @Gromer tnx man :) ill give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect to Gmail's SMTP server on port 587 and specify an SSL connection

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Answer (score 0):

You don't send your credentials and don't specify the SSL port for the SMTP service

```
    var msg = new MailMessage();  
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;  
    msg.Subject = "subject here";  
    msg.Body = "body here";  
    msg.To.Add("email adress here");  

    var client = new SmtpClient();  
    client.EnableSsl = true;  
    client.Port = 465;         
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "mypassword"); 
    client.Send(msg)
```

Comment: they are saved on the web.config

Comment: Woah woah woah there, I see a `Dim` in there!! ;)